# How do I continue and close a path in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

How do I continue and close a path in Adobe Illustrator? I believe the pointer should change to a slash (/) while hovering over the last created node, but it does not.

Comment: There is not enough context to answer the question. This only happens when you use the pen tool. But your poit might not ne reachable, its behind another object, or you have gridsnap on and its not on the grid, its allready closed etc... Or you can use ctrl+j

Comment: Sorry If I was not direct in my question. I mean that when I use the pencil tool, after the first  path I can not continue it, because when I draw the second one the first one disappears. I hope I get to explain myself. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Double-click the Pencil Tool in the toolbar to open the Pencil Tool Options menu. Make sure the **Edit selected paths** option is activated:

[image]

***Note:*** You can also change the close path threshold based on path length in this menu. If you're working with shorter paths, the pencil tool might be closing the path by default.